# How to apply a style to only the first class that occurs?

Tags: css

So I'm trying to apply a specific style to only the first class that occurs on the page with the class name of `.one_third`. I have three columns and three rows with this class, therefore having 9 of these classes altogether. I am trying to make only the first one, being the top left, black in background.

I was attempting to create it myself with Pseudo-classes, and I came up with this:

```
.one_third:first-child
```

Although that made all the classes on the far left black, instead of just the top left one.

I then tried this, to apply it against my `content` div that holds all the classes, yet that failed to do anything.

```
#content > .one_third:first-child
```

How could I achieve this?

EDIT:
This is my exact HTML markup:

[image]

Comment: You can try this, if it works for you: `.one-third:first`

Comment: Typo? You're targeting `.one-third` but the divs have a class of `one_third`. Corrected it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/y5TB3/

Comment: @j08691 - Yeah my bad sorry, will change that now.

Comment: You see the fiddle in my previous comment works right?

Comment: @j08691 - I can see it works with no problem for you... But on my end, no luck at all...

Comment: Then there must be a difference in the code you posted here and in what you have in your real page.

Comment: Would you like to see my URL @j08691 ?

Comment: You didn't post the real code structure, I think.

Comment: I'll post an image from developer tools so you can have a closer look.

Comment: @RCV - Added the correct structure.

Comment: @j08691 - Added the correct structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example,

```
 <div class="jey">
    <p>Number 1</p>
    <p>Number 2</p>
    <p>Number 3</p>
 </div>
 <div class="jey">
    <p>Number 1</p>
    <p>Number 2</p>
    <p>Number 3</p>
 </div>
```

Apply style

```
  .jey:first-of-type{
   background-color:Red;
   }
```

See this http://jsfiddle.net/jeyashri_shri/Td8bx/

and this one also worked in your code

```
 #content .one_third:first-child {
 color:red;
 }
```

But first-child to work in IE, a `'<!DOCTYPE>'` must be declared.
it work on IE7+ but not on IE6 or lower

Comment: Still made all the classes on the left have the background, instead of just the first occurance.

Comment: .one_third:first-of-type{
   background-color:Red;
   }

Comment: check <!DOCTYPE>  also

Comment: Please recheck my HTML structure. Your answer still does the same as I stated before.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<div class="one_third> //you forgot to add closing quote
```

to

```
<div class="one_third">
```

and

```
.one-third:first-child //class name is incorrect
```

to

```
.one_third:first-child
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/daGKd/)

Comment: Hiral, please recheck my post. I had a few typo's since I forgot my class had an underscore, not a hyphen.

Comment: @fizzix make a fiddle.

Comment: @downvoter fizzix changed his post after I answered. Any reason for downvoting??

Comment: Agreed, downvote was not necessary. Gave you an upvote to even it out though ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can check any of the following, if one of them works for you:

```
.clear div.one_third:first-child{
  color:red;
 }

.columns div.one_third:first-child{
  color:red;
 }
```

As you have already used this: `#content div.one_third:first-child{color:red;}` that's why I put those. Check and let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately, both of your solutions still seem to make all classes on the far left have the style, instead of just the first one.